# Cutting files into the clipboard with SWT

Tags: java, swt, clipboard

There are plenty of tutorials out there on how to *copy* files to the clipboard using the SWT API. However, I've never seen an explanation of how to *cut* files to the clipboard. What I'm trying to do is write a simple file manager in Java where you can select a file and press `Ctrl+X`, and when you press `Ctrl+V` *in the native file manager*, the files are moved (not copied) from their original location to the destination. Does the SWT API actually support this, or is some lower-level API required to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this image [sample](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet282.java). Note that there is a [FileTransfer](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/dnd/FileTransfer.html) class instead of ImageTranfer class which you can use instead.

Concerning CUT operation:

[To do this, you must manually erase the data once it is copied to the clipboard. Java provides no implementation of a cut operation.](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip61.html?page=4). This is with AWT/Swing but I am pretty sure it's the same thing with SWT. You can remove it after successful clipboard copy or successful paste...your choice.

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for. If I run this snippet with FileTransfer instead of ImageTransfer, I would only *copy* files to the clipboard, not *cut* them.

Comment: Why don't you copy them and delete them right after a succesfull paste; isn't that what cut/paste does?

Comment: Because I want to paste them into the native file manager, not into my own, and the native one doesn't tell me when the paste operation occurs so I can delete the files.

Comment: The CUT operation instructions link I sent you proposes to delete the data once copied to the clipboard. If you want to delete data on first paste you have an issue here and you might need to use JNI or another way to integrate your SWT application with the native file manager.

Comment: BTW Eclipse does not offer Cut for files so this might be a hint.