# How do I cut a file to the clipboard in Java?

Tags: java, clipboard

I am using this code in a Java Swing application to copy files to the clipboard:

```
final List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
// ... code to fill list omitted ... //

Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(
    new Transferable() {
        @Override
        public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
            return new DataFlavor[] { DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor };
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
            return DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor.equals(flavor);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
            return files;
        }
    }, null
);
```

It works, in that I can go to Windows Explorer and Ctrl+V and the files turn up (hopefully it works in other OSes, though not tested). I'd like to implement **cut** also but I don't know how to let the system know that that's what the action is, or alternatively, how to get feedback for each successfully copied file so I can delete it from its original location manually.

If this isn't impossible, any suggestions on how I should handle this? I'd like to be able to cut & paste within the application too (separately to exchanging files with the OS explorer).

Comment: I don't think cut is possible in Java yet.

Comment: Oh, the code works great in Kubuntu linux (KDE) except for the fact that the Java program must not exit before the user pastes the file. read more here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_selection

Answer (score 1):

There is another post where people discuss the lack of a possibility to cut files:

[Cutting files into the clipboard with SWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481920/cutting-files-into-the-clipboard-with-swt)

If you really need it you could go the ugly way and check if there is a way to do this via JNI-calls, but then you have to do that for all platforms that you want to support...

Answer (score 0):

This is "somewhat" possible using Swing.  See TransferHandler.exportToClipboard().  It offers an action.  The proper way to use exportToClipboard() is to call TransferHandler.getCutAction() and then call actionPerformed() with a newly created ActionEvent() - I use a JComponent with a TransferHandler assigned that will create the Transferable with desired files to put in clipboard.

But the opposite is not possible.  The import from clipboard has no way of knowing if it's cut or copied to clipboard.  TransferHandler.TransferSupport.getDropAction() only works for DND operations.

But maybe it's up to the clipboard owner to delete the files after the transfer is complete.  See TransferHandler.exportDone()

Also see bug http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6673481

Comment: Actually looking at SetClipboardData from Windows API it doesn't look like you can assign a cut or copy action.  I bet Windows Explorer uses another global area to place this info.

Comment: I can't see how to make use of this. I already use all the TransferHandler stuff, but `TransferHandler.exportToClipboard` doesn't actually *use* the `action` parameter to do anything different.

Comment: It just uses the action to call exportDone().  Your right, it doesn't help.  I don't think Java can do it since the clipboard doesn't actually store the action (as far as I can see in Windows).